# What is the difference between chain and chain.from_iterable in itertools?

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I could not find any valid example on the internet where I can see the difference between them and why to choose one over the other.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The first takes 0 or more arguments, each an iterable, the second one takes one argument which is expected to produce the iterables:

```
from itertools import chain

chain(list1, list2, list3)

iterables = [list1, list2, list3]
chain.from_iterable(iterables)
```

but `iterables` can be any iterator that yields the iterables:

```
def gen_iterables():
    for i in range(10):
        yield range(i)

itertools.chain.from_iterable(gen_iterables())
```

Using the second form is usually a case of convenience, but because it loops over the input iterables lazily, it is also the only way you can chain an *infinite* number of finite iterators:

```
def gen_iterables():
    while True:
        for i in range(5, 10):
            yield range(i)

chain.from_iterable(gen_iterables())
```

The above example will give you a iterable that yields a cyclic pattern of numbers that will never stop, but will never consume more memory than what a single `range()` call requires.

Comment: i still can't get it. can you give me the output differnce and use case in practical situation where to use what

Comment: @user1994660: there is no output difference. It's an *input* difference. It makes it easier to use certain inputs.

Comment: @user1994660: I use the second form in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900444/trying-to-add-to-dictionary-values-by-counting-occurrences-in-a-list-of-lists-p/12900577#12900577).

Comment: @user1994660: good usecase for the second form: [Python idiom to chain (flatten) an infinite iterable of finite iterables?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/120886)

Comment: @user1994660: Run this code: `# Return an iterator of iterators` `def it_it():  return iter( [iter( [11, 22] ), iter( [33, 44] )] )`
`print( list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(it_it())) )`
`print( list(itertools.chain(it_it())) )`
`print( list(itertools.chain(*it_it())) )`  The first one is best; the second one doesn't get at the nested iterators, it returns iterators, instead of the desired numbers; the third one produces the correct output BUT it isn't fully lazy: the "*" forced all the iterators to be created. For this dumb input that doesn't matter.

Comment: Note that if the iterables is not too big, you can also do
`itertools.chain(*iterables)`

Comment: @MartijnPieters would you mind if I quoted you on *"the only way you can chain a infinite number of finite iterators"*?

Comment: I recently added chain.from_iterable to [a c++ project](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools)

Answer (score 19):

> I could not find any valid example ... where I can see the difference between them [`chain` and `chain.from_iterable`] and why to choose one over the other

The accepted answer is thorough.  For those seeking a quick application, consider flattening several lists:

```
list(itertools.chain(["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e"], ["f"]))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

You may wish to reuse these lists later, so you make an iterable of lists:

```
iterable = (["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e"], ["f"])
```

**Attempt**

However, passing in an iterable to `chain` gives an unflattened result:

```
list(itertools.chain(iterable))
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f']]
```

Why?  You passed in *one* item (a tuple).  `chain` needs each list separately.

---

**Solutions**

When possible, you can unpack an iterable:

```
list(itertools.chain(*iterable))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

list(itertools.chain(*iter(iterable)))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

More generally, use `.from_iterable` (as it also works with infinite iterators):

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(iterable))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

g = itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.cycle(iterable))
next(g)
# "a"
```

Answer (score 9):

They do very similar things. For small number of iterables `itertools.chain(*iterables)` and `itertools.chain.from_iterable(iterables)` perform similarly.

The key advantage of `from_iterables` lies in the ability to handle large (potentially infinite) number of iterables since all of them need not be available at the time of the call.

Comment: Does anyone know if the `*` operator unpacks `iterables` lazily?

Comment: @Rotareti, yes it does unpack lazily (one at a time) but in this case `itertools.chain(*iterables)` is a function call. All arguments must be present at the time of call.

Comment: Is this true? From the CPython code, it seems to be the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513808/610569

Comment: @alvas Try changing the number of elements to very large; in the range of 10_000 to 1_000_000 and you will see the `from_iterables` becoming faster.

Answer (score 6):

Extending [@martijn-pieters answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15004794/610569)

Although the access to the inner items in the iterable remains the same, and implementation wise,

- `itertools_chain_from_iterable` (i.e. `chain.from_iterable` in Python) and
- `chain_new` (i.e. `chain` in Python)

in the CPython implementation, are both duck-types of [chain_new_internal](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47a23fc63fa5df2da8dbc542e78e521d4a7f10c9/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L1868)

---

**Are there any optimization benefits from using `chain.from_iterable(x)`, where `x` is an iterable of iterable; and the main purpose is to ultimately consume the flatten list of items?**

We can try benchmarking it with:

```
import random
from itertools import chain
from functools import wraps
from time import time

from tqdm import tqdm

def timing(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        ts = time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time()
        print('func:%r args:[%r, %r] took: %2.4f sec' % (f.__name__, args, kw, te-ts))
        return result
    return wrap

def generate_nm(m, n):
    # Creates m generators of m integers between range 0 to n.
    yield iter(random.sample(range(n), n) for _ in range(m))
    

def chain_star(x):
    # Stores an iterable that will unpack and flatten the list of list.
    chain_x = chain(*x)
    # Consumes the items in the flatten iterable.
    for i in chain_x:
        pass

def chain_from_iterable(x):
    # Stores an iterable that will unpack and flatten the list of list.
    chain_x = chain.from_iterable(x)
    # Consumes the items in the flatten iterable.
    for i in chain_x:
        pass


@timing
def versus(f, n, m):
  f(generate_nm(n, m))
```

P/S: Benchmark running... Waiting for the results.

---

## Results

### chain_star, m=1000, n=1000

```
for _ in range(10):
    versus(chain_star, 1000, 1000)
```

[out]:

```
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6494 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6603 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6367 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6350 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6296 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6399 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6341 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6381 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6343 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6309 sec
```

### chain_from_iterable, m=1000, n=1000

```
for _ in range(10):
    versus(chain_from_iterable, 1000, 1000)
```

[out]:

```
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6416 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6315 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6535 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6334 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6327 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6471 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6426 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6287 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6353 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 1000, 1000), {}] took: 0.6297 sec
```

### chain_star, m=10000, n=1000

```
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2659 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2966 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2953 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.3141 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2802 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2799 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2848 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.3299 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2730 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.3052 sec
```

### chain_from_iterable, m=10000, n=1000

```
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.3129 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.3064 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.3071 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2660 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2837 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2877 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2756 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2939 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2715 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 10000, 1000), {}] took: 6.2877 sec
```

### chain_star, m=100000, n=1000

```
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.7874 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 63.3744 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.5584 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 63.3745 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.7982 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 63.4054 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.6769 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.6476 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 63.7397 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.8980 sec
```

### chain_from_iterable, m=100000, n=1000

```
for _ in range(10):
    versus(chain_from_iterable, 100000, 1000)
```

[out]:

```
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.7227 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.7717 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.7159 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.7569 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.7906 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.6211 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.7294 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.8260 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.8356 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 100000, 1000), {}] took: 62.9738 sec
```

### chain_star, m=500000, n=1000

```
for _ in range(3):
    versus(chain_from_iterable, 500000, 1000)
```

[out]:

```
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 500000, 1000), {}] took: 314.5671 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 500000, 1000), {}] took: 313.9270 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_star at 0x7f5c7188ef28>, 500000, 1000), {}] took: 313.8992 sec
```

### chain_from_iterable, m=500000, n=1000

```
for _ in range(3):
    versus(chain_from_iterable, 500000, 1000)
```

[out]:

```
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 500000, 1000), {}] took: 313.8301 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 500000, 1000), {}] took: 313.8104 sec
func:'versus' args:[(<function chain_from_iterable at 0x7f5c7188eb70>, 500000, 1000), {}] took: 313.9440 sec
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to see it:

`chain(iterable1, iterable2, iterable3, ...)` is for when you already know what iterables you have, so you can write them as these comma-separated arguments.

`chain.from_iterable(iterable)` is for when your iterables (like iterable1, iterable2, iterable3) are obtained from another iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it is to use `chain.from_iterable`

when you have an iterable of iterables like a nested iterable(or a compound iterbale) and use `chain` for simple iterables.