# Union of all keys from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have a list of dictionaries. They mostly have the same keys in each row, but a few don't match and have extra key/value pairs. Is there a fast way to get a set of all the keys in all the rows?

Right now I'm using this loop:

```
def get_all_keys(dictlist):
    keys = set()
    for row in dictlist:
        keys = keys.union(row.keys())
```

It just seems terribly inefficient to do this on a list with hundreds of thousands of rows, but I'm not sure how to do it better

Thanks!

Comment: `set([row.keys() for row in dictlist])` is *not* what you wanted. Besides, it results in a `TypeError`.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't actually tried that one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try:

```
def all_keys(dictlist):
    return set().union(*dictlist)
```

Avoids imports, and will make the most of the underlying implementation of `set`. Will also work with anything iterable.

Comment: Thanks! That works, but I'm not sure why. Can you help me understand what the asterisk is doing in this case? How is it that it only extracts the keys from `dictlist`?

Comment: Sure... The `*` unpacks the list into separate arguments to [set.union](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) which can take any number of iterable arguments... (so the above call is effectively set().union(first_dict, second_dict, third_dict, fourth_dict...) So for each object in the list, it attempts to iterate over it (which in the case of a `dict` is its keys, or a list/tuple its items, or for a string its characters.... etc...)

Comment: Ahh, thank you. This helps me understand what the asterisk is useful for too.

Answer (score 4):

A fun one which works on python3.x<sup>1</sup> relies on `reduce` and the fact the `dict.keys()` now returns a set-like object:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> dicts = [{1:2},{3:4},{5:6}]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x | y.keys(),dicts,{})
{1, 3, 5}
```

For what it's worth,

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x | y.keys(),dicts,set())
{1, 3, 5}
```

works too, or, if you want to avoid a `lambda` (and the initializer), you could even do:

```
>>> reduce(operator.or_, (d.keys() for d in dicts))
```

Very neat.

This really shines most when you only have two elements.  Then, instead of doing something like `set(a) | set(b)`, you can do `a.keys() | b.keys()` which seems a little nicer to me.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>It can be made to work on python2.7 as well.  Use `dict.viewkeys` instead of `dict.keys`</sup>

Comment: Not convinced you need method calls for either... `reduce(set.union, dicts, set())` should just work I believe...

Comment: @JonClements -- True.  My thought here was more to demonstrate the set-like nature of `dict.keys` in python3.x

Comment: Umm, okay - `reduce(operator.or_, (d.keys() for d in dicts))` ?

Comment: @JonClements -- Yeah, I like that one.  I'll update using that.

Answer (score 3):

you can do:

```
from itertools import chain
return set(chain.from_iterable(dictlist))
```

As @Jon Clements noted, this can keep only the required data in memory, in contrast to using the `*` operator for either `chain` or `union`.

Comment: What does `chain` do here?

Comment: That won't work -- it would try to make a set from each dictionary.  You'd need `set(chain.from_iterable(dictlist))` or something.

Comment: I'd go with @DSM here - definitely `chain.from_iterable` - it's basically `chain(*dictlist)` but more optimised (and a bit more explicit IMHO)...

Comment: @JonClements, I don't see an advantage of `chain.from_iterable` here. Since the dicts and dictlist all exist already, there is no saving.

Comment: @gnibbler dictlist may be any iterable. Not only a list.

Comment: @Blender can you explain your question?

Comment: @Elazar, that also works with tuple unpacking of *args. The key difference is just when the iterator providing the dicts is consumed.

Comment: @Elazar: `chain(dictlist) == dictlist`, so `chain` wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Here's one related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004772/what-is-the-difference-between-chain-and-chain-from-iterable-in-itertools

Answer (score 1):

`sets`are like dictionaries, and have an `update()` method, so this would work in your loop:

```
keys.update(row.iterkeys())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about performance, you should quit the `dict.keys()` method, since it creates a list in memory. And you can use `set.update()` instead of union, but I don't know if it is faster than `set.union()`.