# Iterating over first iteration in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested, iteration

Is there a one-liner or Pythonic (I'm aware that the former doesn't necessarily imply the latter) way to write the following nested loop?

```
for i in some_list:
    for j in i:
        # do something
```

I've tried

```
import itertools
for i,j in itertools.product(some_list,i):
    # do something
```

but I get a 'reference before assignment error', which makes sense, I think. I've been unable to find an answer to this question so far... Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Use list complehension it will use as onliner instead of loop in pythonic way.

Comment: @Lafada: nested list comprehensions are not that pythonic (they can be hard to read), **and** in any way using list comprehensions for side effects is definitly unpythonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate through each sub-list in `some_list` in turn you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
for j in itertools.chain(*some_list):
```

A short demo:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> some_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> for j in itertools.chain(*some_list):
    print j


1
2
3
4
```

Alternatively there is [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> for j in itertools.chain.from_iterable(some_list):
    print j


1
2
3
4
```

*(Aside from the slight syntax change, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15004794/3001761) for an explanation of the difference.)*

Comment: You mean I can still use this for dictionaries? I can see how it works for lists of lists, but don't see how it would work for a list of dictionaries. Could you show me please?

Comment: The answer is "it depends". For what you're trying to do, no, although if you just wanted to iterate over the list values you could do `for j in itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(itemgetter("some_key"), some_list)): print j`.

Answer (score 1):

Use chain:

```
import itertools


some_list = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6]]

for i in itertools.chain(*some_list):
    print i
1
2
3
4
3
4
5
6
```