# More simplified explanation of chain.from_iterable and chain() of itertools

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-itertools, chain

Can you give a more simplified explanation of these two methods `chain()` and `chain.from_iterable` from `itertools`?

I have searched the knowledge base and as well the python documentation but i got confused.

I am new to python that's why I am asking a more simplified explanation regarding these.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand how generators work in python?  If not, it's probably best to start there.

Comment: Have you tried writing some code? It usually helps me to understand things I've read. Come up with a [mcve] to show what you don't understand.

Comment: No, like I have said earlier, I am ramping up to learn Python. What I read about generators is that is a simplified way to loop to create a list or a dictionary. You may correct me if I am wrong on this part.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15004772/610569

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain sequences to make a single sequence:

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(chain(a, b))
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

If `a` and `b` are in another sequence, instead of having to unpack them and pass them to `chain` you can pass the whole sequence to `from_iterable`:

```
>>> c = [a, b]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(c))
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

It creates a sequence by iterating over the sub-sequences of your main sequence. This is sometimes called flattening a list. If you want to flatten lists of lists of lists, you'll have to code that yourself. There are plenty of questions and answers about that on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

We can learn about the difference between these two tools by looking at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
def chain(*iterables):
    # chain('ABC', 'DEF') --> A B C D E F
    ...

def from_iterable(iterable):
    # chain.from_iterable(['ABC', 'DEF']) --> A B C D E F
    ...
```

The key difference is in the signatures and how they handle an [iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols), which is something that can be iterated or looped over.

- `chain` accepts iterables, such as `"ABC", "DEF"` or `[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]`.
- `chain.from_iterable` accepts one iterable, often a nested iterable, e.g. `"ABCDEF"` or `[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]`.  This is helpful for a flattening nested iterables.  See its direct implementation in the `flatten` tool found in the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Answer (score 0):

chain excepts one or more iterables as argument and returns iterator consists of each items from iterables

like below

```
import itertools
for x in chain([1,2,3],(4,5,6)): #note can also accept different data types(list and tupe )
    print(x,end=' ')
#output
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

chain.from_iterable accepts single iterable as argument

```
for x in chain.from_iterable(['ABC']):  # the iterable argument with nested 
iterable(**'ABC' is again iterable**) 
    print(x,end=' ')
#output 
A B C
```

Whereas this does not work

```
for x in chain.from_iterable([1,2,3]): 
    print(x,end=' ')
    #TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```