# How can I test several sets for items that are unique in Python?

Tags: python, set, unique

I'm looking for a way to find the unique items between several sets. For example, take these 3 sets.

```py
x = {1, 2}
y = {1, 3}
z = {1, 3, 4, 5}
```

How can I find the unique items? I'm looking for something like this.

```py
findunique(x, y, z) # {2, 4, 5}
```

I tried using `symmetric_difference` with `reduce`,  but that ended up returning `{1, 2, 4, 5}`.

The only other thing I can think of is to have a `dict` keep track of how many counts there are for each item, and return only the ones with 1 count. However, that seems very inefficient and unpythonic. What's the "right" way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the sets into one list with `chain`. Count the number of occurrences of each item with `Counter`. Select the items that occur only once and make a set of them.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

sets = x,y,z
{x for x, cnt in Counter(chain.from_iterable(sets)).items() if cnt==1}
#{2, 4, 5}
```

**EDITED** based on the comments by @jedwards.

Comment: Why not simply `{x for x, cnt in Counter(chain(x, y, z)).items() if cnt==1}`?

Comment: @jedwards No big difference, but using `from_iterable` is [considered more elegant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004772/what-is-the-difference-between-chain-and-chain-from-iterable-in-itertools).

Comment: Is it considered more elegant to needlessly create lists using `map(list, ...)`?

Comment: @jedwards That part is indeed redundant.

Comment: @DYZ What about star notation? `Counter(chain(*sets))`

Comment: @Daffy `chain(*sets)` is simply `chain(x, y, z)` in disguise. So, same answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten the `sets` after converting them to a single list and then filter it for items with count that equal 1.

```
lista = [x, y, z]
listb = [j for i in lista for j in i]
print(set(filter(lambda x: listb.count(x) == 1, listb)))
# {2, 4, 5}
```