# Python: Add occurrences of a list element and its total count to another list, avoid adding duplicates

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have a corpus of text containing sentences.
I wish to count the number of occurrences of each word and avoid adding any word more than once (e.g. Multiple occurrences of ',' must be added once to return something like `',': 2047`)

Desired output:`'partner': 7, 'meetings': 7, '14': 7, 'going': 7,`etc.
I realize that I need to use a `set()` to avoid duplicates. But I don't know how. Currently, I am avoiding adding elements that are already in the list by saying `append only if not already in occurrences`

This however isn't working as I am getting `',':2047` multiple times in the result.

I am avoiding list comprehensions in the sample code to increase reader's comprehension! :P

Counting occurrences of words[i] in words

```
occurrences = []
for i in range(1, words.__len__() - 1):
    if words[i-1] not in occurrences:
        occurrences.append((words[i - 1], words.count(words[i - 1])))
print(occurrences)
```

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`

Comment: I believe my question is easier to quickly grasp with the expected output compared to the question it is a duplicate of. IDC if this one is deleted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
word_count = Counter(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900577/3343130) I should use Counter() like so:

```
from collections import Counter
ctr = Counter()
    for word in words:
        ctr[word] += 1
    print(ctr)
```